# VBA Page Header Dont Want to Find Time &T

Tags: excel, vba, variables, header

Trying to automatically create a header based on the name of a company.
One of the entries has &T in the name and I can not figure out how to keep the entire company, and not call the time.

```
With WB.Sheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
.CenterHeader ="random words" &companyName & "more words" &otherVariable
```

Lets say the company is AT&T, rather then getting the header:
"Random words AT&T more words othervariable"
I am getting:
"Random words AT4:01PM more words othervariable"

The &T in the header defaults to the time, have tried various combinations of quotes but not sure what else to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `companyName`, use `Replace(companyName, "&", "&&")` (similarly for others). Doubled ampersands display as a single ampersand in headers, instead of being interpolated.